# Instafeed : invalid media id

Tags: instafeedjs

I try to use instafeed.js to display the 10 last instagram post from my account, on my magento website.

Here is my script :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        var feed = new Instafeed({
            clientId: 'myclientid',
            accessToken: 'myaccesstoken',
            template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
            sortBy: 'most-recent',
            limit: '10',
            resolution: 'thumbnail'
        });
        feed.run();
</script>
```

It returns me an error : Error from Instagram: invalid media id

Of course my instagram application is in sandbox mode, and from what I read on the instragram website, it will stay at this state for this kind of use.
And I've unchecked the OAuth security.

I don't understand what I means by 'invalid media id'.
Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to post images from your own account, then you need to set the `get` and `userId` options accordingly:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',      // <-- new
    userId: 'xxxx',   // <-- new
    clientId: 'myclientid',
    accessToken: 'myaccesstoken',
    template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    limit: '10',
    resolution: 'thumbnail'
});
feed.run();
```

Without those options set, Instafeed.js will try and pull the "popular" media from Instagram, which has been removed from their API, and is no longer valid.